# How to create an ajax POST request with multiple request headers using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Let me start by saying I am new very new to JavaScript and have never made an ajax POST before.

I wrote this ajax POST request, but don't know how to add it to a JavaScript function (or if the ajax is complete).

I need to pass multiple variables into this script (see places that say VARIABLE). I also need to pass several request headers.  Am I doing this correctly?

Any help with code review is much appreciated. Thanks!

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  data: {
    queryId: "VARIABLE",
    responseId: "VARIABLE"
  }
  headers: {
    'authority': 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    'method': 'POST',
    'path': 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'content-length': '34',
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'origin': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36',
    'referer': 'VARIABLE',
    'cookie': 'VARIABLE',
  }
});
```

Comment: Your AJAX call looks fine. As such the question becomes 'How do I create a function with arguments?' and that can be answered [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: Rory McCrossan's advice is good. You may also want to read about [asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) which is what you will need to know next.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the info!